# How is Dart VM's performance compared to Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dart

I would like to start a new Nodejs project soon, and I was wondering if I should try out Dart VM instead. I read that Dart VM is not finished yet, but I should already have everything I need (web server, sockets, files i/o), and I would enjoy discovering something new.

Does anyone have experience with both Node and DartVM, and can tell me what are the major differences/problems to expect, or if Dart VM is really not usable for real server side projects yet?

I'm not asking for your personal preferences, but for actual problems I might encounter based on your experience.

Comment: Dart VM are usable if you don't mind that it is not tested in combat. That is to say, if you want to take the fire itself, you can try. That's when support Dart VM officially add in Googe Chrome browser then it really will be felt by millions of users. At the moment, with it only played enthusiasts. P.S. The server Dart VM is the same virtual machine that will later be built into the browser. Go for it!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that node's [ecosystem](https://www.npmjs.org/) is nearly two orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: I wrote a URL unshortener in dart to test it out. No caching or anything (just a toy). It's something with enough complexity to get a taste of the language on the server. If you want to take a look at the code, you can find it here: https://gist.github.com/qubyte/8513745

Comment: The DartVM is ~2x of V8. However node.js has a faster HTTP server than Dart also ~2x. See server benchmarks here http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/ . And VM benchmarks here https://www.dartlang.org/performance/ . Perhaps change your question to "are there any benchmarks comparing DartVM and Node.js", and then it could be unlocked by the admins.

Comment: @GregLowe Really? That benchmark is for testing JSON serialization. That too chart is for peak responses p/s. Did you see latency and other critera. Please take benchmark results with pinch of salt.

Comment: @user568109 There are several different benchmarks (tabs at the bottom), it's actually very useful information.

Comment: @user568109 Node.js uses a optimized C library for its HTTP parsing (joyent I believe). Dart's HttpServer is mostly written in Dart. Apparently there is some work in the pipeline to improve it. Related: I saw a plus post about a 15x improvement on websocket handling due to use of SIMD. Also worth considering - for any application that actually runs a reasonable amount of code, the HTTP overhead is likely to be minimal fraction of the overall request time. Given that its performance is already ok - and likely to get better, I wouldn't let these benchmarks put you off using it.

Comment: @GregLowe Which is why I added with a pinch of salt. When someone says 15x improvement, I can only think of corner cases where one outperforms the other. Benchmarks like these turn out to be less than meaningful. For the same benchmark you quote the avg latency for node.js is way less than dart, which means that nodejs handles concurrent connections really well. Dart on the other hand had one of the highest peak responses which really does not mean anything concrete.   It could be because of abrupt completion of older responses. How does that mean 2x performance ?

Comment: @GregLowe There is a reason why such questions are opinion-based. How the poster interprets his benchmarks is very important. Benchmarks done by one person may not be of much use to others. And many times they apply only to miniscule number of cases. Base your question with facts, i.e. your own findings/benchmarks.

Comment: @user568109 Yes many pinches of salt taken, and the Dart HttpServer impl still runs slow - have a look with apachebench yourself. The original developer acknowledges this and says improvements are on the way. As I said above, depending on your application, the slower HTTP performance may not make a big difference to overall response times. Links to relevant discussions: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/yYNRbBm0zmM/PtLlUVJwA48J  and https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/_u1lRr-LZ84/MjOm6NrR_B8J

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/H-bMhfAOVvs/GlwToRgw5cAJ  https://plus.google.com/100258330325630692559/posts/RzcppgT9j5T "WebSocket throughput improved by 15x" If you have questions about this post on the thread.

Comment: @GregLowe I wont care to check those links or ask a new question. Just explain how is dartvm performing twice w.r.to the benchmark you quote.

Comment: This is a good question for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Like Seth says, if you still have some cud to chew, then probably better to move this conversation. In a helloworld httpserver app, last time I looked, Node beats the DartVM by ~2x on throughput, this is plain to see on the techempower plaintext test or with apachebench on your own computer. I don't get what your beef with this statement is. This is a known issue and being worked on - as stated by the original developer of the Dart HttpServer in the links provided. On a number of raw computation benchmarks, Dart beats V8 by around 2x. See https://www.dartlang.org/performance/

Comment: but why this could be happened? http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=i7&test=plaintext&l=2tc0

Comment: @Kokizzu The benchmarks are useless. I would point out that peak responses per second is a dubious way to measure throughput (at least require some context). The JSON searialization benchmark shows different results for other platforms, like nodejs beating dart. Forget what Greg asserts regarding performance. This question is closed for a reason, it is very opinion-based.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I worked on a small project, a few months ago, using Dart as a server side language. I really enjoyed it and didn't have any specific problem beside the occasional "there's no package for that" - there are way more packages for Node than for Dart. This could be something to consider for development speed (no need to reinvent the wheel). Other than that, everything went fine.

As a note, it is being used live by others: [top 5 live websites already using Dart](http://divingintodart.blogspot.dk/2013/09/top-5-live-websites-already-using-dart.html)